# Global Keyboard Hook for OSX 10.10.3

Tags: macos, keylogger

I am trying to get a global keyboard hook for OSX 10.10.3. It would ideally be neatly packaged in a Java library, but at this point I just want something that works.

I've tried two routes, and both produce the same results: I am able to read touchpad activity, external mouse activity, and keypresses of the "control", "option", "command", and "shift" keys. Keypresses on all other keys do not trigger any activity.

Both JNativeHook and a native application using quartz event taps produce that result, so I assume at some level they hit the same API. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is the Cocoa method `+[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:]`.  For either this or event taps to see keyboard events, your app must be "trusted for accessibility access".  For instance look up `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions`.